# How do I get 'real-time' information back from a subprocess.Popen in python (2.5)

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen

I'd like to use the subprocess module in the following way:

1. create a new process that potentially takes a long time to execute.
2. capture `stdout` (or `stderr`, or potentially both, either together or separately)
3. Process data from the subprocess **as it comes in,** perhaps firing events on every line received (in wxPython say) or simply printing them out for now.

I've created processes with Popen, but if I use communicate() the data comes at me all at once, once the process has terminated.

If I create a separate thread that does a blocking `readline()` of `myprocess.stdout` (using `stdout = subprocess.PIPE`)  I don't get any lines with this method either, until the process terminates. (no matter what I set as bufsize)

Is there a way to deal with this that isn't horrendous, and works well on multiple platforms?

Comment: myprocess.stdout.readline() should work. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Unbuffered reads from popen_obj.stdout() should indeed work -- but if you don't mind being limited to platforms with PTY support, your application might be suitable for the Pexpect library.

Comment: This is a great question and it still seems to be unanswered, at least for the "works well on multiple platforms" requirement.

Comment: related: [Getting realtime output using subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess)

Comment: here's how [to capture and display in "real-time" time both stdout and stderr separately from a child process line by line in a portable manner in a single thread in Python 3 (`asyncio`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960956/4279) and here's [multithreaded solution (`teed_call()`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279).

Comment: here's [how to  read subprocess' output in a GUI (threads/no threads solutions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627148/tkinter-subprocess-locking-gui-and-not-returning-stdout-to-text#comment34460372_22627148)

Answer (score 8):

Update with code that appears not to work (on windows anyway)

```
class ThreadWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, callable, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ThreadWorker, self).__init__()
        self.callable = callable
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except wx.PyDeadObjectError:
            pass
        except Exception, e:
            print e



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    def worker(pipe):
        while True:
            line = pipe.readline()
            if line == '': break
            else: print line

    proc = Popen("python subprocess_test.py", shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    stdout_worker = ThreadWorker(worker, proc.stdout)
    stderr_worker = ThreadWorker(worker, proc.stderr)
    stdout_worker.start()
    stderr_worker.start()
    while True: pass
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer. Thanks for showing me this 'pipe' type in Python!

Comment: This is a great answer, and works for me. The key is that the reads can block without any problem due to the threads.

Comment: `while True: time.sleep(1)` is better than a busy wait loop consuming all your CPU.

Comment: How does it fail on Windows?

Comment: call `proc.stdin.close()` if you use `stdin=PIPE`. Use `for t in [stdout_worker, stderr_workerr]: t.join()` instead of `while True:pass`. You could use `iter(pipe.readline, b'')` instead of the while loop in `worker()`.

Answer (score 7):

stdout will be buffered - so you won't get anything till that buffer is filled, or the subprocess exits.

You can try flushing `stdout` from the sub-process, or using stderr, or changing stdout on non-buffered mode.

Comment: Shouldn't it be unbuffered by default? At least with bufsize=0 ?

Comment: @Albert: the buffer is *inside* subprocess e.g., `stdio` buffer. Nothing outside the child process sees that data until it flushes its stdout buffer. Here're some workarounds for [the buffering issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509641/4279)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the issue might be the use of buffered output by the subprocess - if a relatively small amount of output is created, it could be buffered until the subprocess exits.  Some background can be found [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/):

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

```
cmd = ["./tester_script.bash"]
p = subprocess.Popen( cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
while p.poll() is None:
    out = p.stdout.readline()
    do_something_with( out, err )
```

In your case you could try to pass a reference to the sub-process to your Worker Thread, and do the polling inside the thread. I don't know how it will behave when two threads poll (and interact with) the same subprocess, but it may work.

Also note thate the `while p.poll() is None:` is intended as is. Do **not** replace it with `while not p.poll()` as in python `0` (the returncode for successful termination) is also considered `False`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing here but it seems like your code is actually blocking: that "while" loop means that whatever the output of that function should be, it won't be returned until p.poll() is None.

Comment: Yes. This is blocking. I guess that back when I answered this, I did not notice the threading part of the question. Even so, my answer here is not quite "up-to-date". The main problem is that output is buffered (as mentioned elsewhere), and I don't mention this here. I will leave it here for posterity, but other submitted answers are better.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into this problem as well. The problem occurs because you are trying to read stderr as well. If there are no errors, then trying to read from stderr would block.

On Windows, there is no easy way to poll() file descriptors (only Winsock sockets).

So a solution is not to try and read from stderr.

Answer (score 1):

Using pexpect [http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect] with non-blocking readlines will resolve this problem.  It stems from the fact that pipes are buffered, and so your app's output is getting buffered by the pipe, therefore you can't get to that output until the buffer fills or the process dies.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a well-known Python limitation, see 
[PEP 3145](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3145/) and maybe others.

Answer (score 1):

Read one character at a time: http://blog.thelinuxkid.com/2013/06/get-python-subprocess-output-without.html

```
import contextlib
import subprocess

# Unix, Windows and old Macintosh end-of-line
newlines = ['\n', '\r\n', '\r']
def unbuffered(proc, stream='stdout'):
    stream = getattr(proc, stream)
    with contextlib.closing(stream):
        while True:
            out = []
            last = stream.read(1)
            # Don't loop forever
            if last == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
                break
            while last not in newlines:
                # Don't loop forever
                if last == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
                    break
                out.append(last)
                last = stream.read(1)
            out = ''.join(out)
            yield out

def example():
    cmd = ['ls', '-l', '/']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        # Make all end-of-lines '\n'
        universal_newlines=True,
    )
    for line in unbuffered(proc):
        print line

example()
```

Comment: it seems to be a duplicate answer. See [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess/15288921#comment41473849_15288921)

Answer (score 1):

Using subprocess.Popen, I can run the .exe of one of my C# projects and redirect the output to my Python file. I am able now to `print()` all the information being output to the C# console (using `Console.WriteLine()`) to the Python console.

Python code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen('ConsoleDataImporter.exe', stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT, shell = True)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print(line)
    if not line:
        break
```

This gets the console output of my .NET project line by line as it is created and breaks out of the enclosing while loop upon the project's termination. I'd imagine this would work for two python files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the pexpect module for this, it seems to work ok. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/