# python subprocesses (of process with subprocesses) on termination hang in OSX activity monitor

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, multiprocessing

I'm writing a test harness for a udp server I wrote. The idea is to use a multiprocessing.pool to do  subprocess.call commands for several instances of the server ([per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884650/how-to-spawn-parallel-child-processes-on-a-multi-processor-system)). The udp server is another python program which consists of 3 processes (main, http interface and udp server). In my attempts to write a test script, when I kill the test script with CTRL+C, I always get 2-5 hanging python2.7 processes in my activity monitor.

My attempts:

1. vanilla subprocess
2. subprocess that handles bash not connected to terminal ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151640/pythons-subprocess-popen-object-hangs-gathering-child-output-when-child-process))
3. multiprocess.pool, also creates hanging process using simple test.py script (see below)

I've tried adding subprocess kills in the server code to no avail. When I run the server inside a terminal, it responds to CTRL+C correctly. I assume it's something with the child processes inside the server, because (1) and (2) have no problems with the test.py script.

---

1) just using subprocesses:

```
args0 = [sys.executable, server_path, '-p', '7000', '-t', '8000', '-u', '9000']
args1 = [sys.executable, server_path, '-p', '7001', '-t', '8001', '-u', '9001']

p0 = subprocess.Popen(args0)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(args1)
```

2) using subprocesses with stdout, pipe, os.kill:

```
p0 = subprocess.Popen(  args0, 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
                        close_fds=True)
print "running for 5s..."
time.sleep(5)
os.kill(p0.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

3a) test_harness.py (with pool)

```
import sys, os, time
import subprocess, multiprocessing

def work(cmd):
    return subprocess.call(cmd) # , shell=False

def main():
    server_path = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'test.py'

    args0 = [sys.executable, server_path, '-p', '7000']
    # args1 = [sys.executable, server_path, '-p', '7001']
    tasks = [args0]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    pool.map_async(work, tasks)
    time.sleep(3)
    pool.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

3b) test.py

```
def main():
    while True:
        a = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well, if `os.kill(p0.pid, signal.SIGTERM)` doesn't kill the subprocess, it sounds like your subprocess is ignoring `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working finally. This code spawns two multithreaded server instances, as subprocesses inside a test harness. You get get all console output from the subprocess, and when you CTRL+C the test harness from the terminal, all the subprocesses die too. `subprocess.Popen` didn't work for me ultimately.

```
def runInstance(args):
    # NOTE: We don't do the stdout or stderr args
    p = subprocess.call(args, 
                        # stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        # stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
                        close_fds=True, 
                        shell=True
                        )

def main():
    print "Starting test harness..."
    server_path = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'server.py'
    args0 = [sys.executable, server_path, '-p', '7000', '-t', '8000', '-u', '9000']
    args1 = [sys.executable, server_path, '-p', '7001', '-t', '8001', '-u', '9001']

    # Start server instances
    # NOTE: It is target=runInstance, not target=runInstance()
    p0 = multiprocessing.Process(target=runInstance, args=(' '.join(args0),))
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=runInstance, args=(' '.join(args1),))
    p0.start()
    p1.start()
```