# Shell hangs after killing subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I know there are a bunch of similar questions on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624254/how-do-i-close-the-stdout-pipe-when-killing-a-process-started-with-python-subpro) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151640/pythons-subprocess-popen-object-hangs-gathering-child-output-when-child-process) and maybe a couple more, but none of them seem to apply in my particular situation. My lack of understanding on how `subprocess.Popen()` works doesn't help either.

What i want to achieve is:  launch a subprocess (a command line radio player) that also outputs data to the terminal and can also receive input -- wait for a while -- terminate the subprocess -- exit the shell. I am running python 2.7 on OSX 10.9

**Case 1.**
This launches the radio player (but audio only!), terminates the process, exits.

```
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'mplayer http://173.239.76.147:8090'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
time.sleep(5)
p.kill()
```

**Case 2.**
This launches the radio player, outputs information like radio name, song, bitrate, etc and also accepts input. It terminates the subprocess but it never exists the shell and the terminal becomes unusable even after using 'Ctrl-C'.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'mplayer http://173.239.76.147:8090'],
                     shell=False)
time.sleep(5)
p.kill()
```

Any ideas on how to do it? I was even thinking at the possibility of opening a *slave-shell* for the subprocess if there is no other choice (of course it is also something that I don't have a clue about). Thanks!

Comment: Note that instead of using `kill()` you should probably use `terminate()`. Applications usually handle `SIGTERM` better. In fact I can confirm you that using `.terminate()` the audio player exits saying `Exiting... (Quit)`, while using `.kill()` I don't get any feedback. However even in this case the terminal is a bit screwed.

Comment: Also Why are you using `/bin/bash` to execute the command? You should use: `Popen(['mplayer', 'http://173.239.76.147:8090'])` to launch a simple subprocess.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes you are right about using `terminate()` instead of `kill()` and with `/bin/bash` it's a bad habit I guess. However none of your suggestions fix my actual problem unfortunately...

Comment: unrelated: *always* feed/consume pipes that are set to `PIPE` otherwise the child process may block forever doing nothing either expecting input or trying to write output. If you want to discard input/output; use `subprocess.DEVNULL` or `DEVNULL=open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm not sure I understand how this works… I need the output of the subprocess to be displayed not to go to `/dev/null`. I don't know how to make sure that everything is 'flushed' after the process terminates.

Comment: @HerrActress: if your actual code uses `p.stdin`, `p.stdout` e.g., by calling `p.communicate()` then it is fine. You could have mentioned it in a code comment. I often see that people copy-paste the code without understanding what it does. Related: [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like `mplayer` uses the `curses` library and when `kill()`ing it or `terminate()`ing it, for some reason, it doesn't clean the library state correctly.

To restore the terminal state you can use the `reset` command.

Demo:

```
import subprocess, time

p = subprocess.Popen(['mplayer', 'http://173.239.76.147:8090'])
time.sleep(5)
p.terminate()
p.wait()  # important!

subprocess.Popen(['reset']).wait()

print('Hello, World!')
```

In principle it should be possible to use `stty sane` too, but it doesn't work well for me.

---

As Sebastian points out, there was a missing `wait()` call in the above code (now added). With this `wait()` call *and* using `terminate()` the terminal doesn't get messed up (and so there shouldn't be any need for `reset`).

Without the `wait()` I sometimes do have problems of mixed output between the python process and `mplayer`.

Also, a solution specific to `mplayer`, as pointed out by Sebastian, is to send a `q` to the stdin of `mplayer` to quit it.

I leave the code that uses `reset` because it works with *any* program that uses the `curses` library, whether it correctly tears down the library or not, and thus it might be useful in other situations where a clean exit isn't possible.

Comment: @Herr Actress: add `p.wait()` after `p.terminate()`: it avoids zombies and it *might* wait for the child process to  restore the terminal by itself before exiting. Use `subprocess.check_call([..])` instead of `rc = Popen([..]).wait(); if rc != 0: raise Error`. You could also try `p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` instead of `p.terminate()` to see if it would allow to avoid calling `reset`. See also [Stop reading process output in Python without hang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4417962/4279)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian I have tried with `p.wait()` after `terminate` but the process just hangs forever… Also it is very hard to 'build' a solution from your comments, so please feel free to post it as an answer if you feel there is a more pythonic way than using `reset`

Comment: @HerrActress: `p.wait()` doesn't make the child process hang. It just waits for its exit status. It means that you have to use `p.kill()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Right, I believe that I incorrectly deleted that `wait()` sometime when investigating the problem. And indeed, adding it `reset` doesn't seem to be needed calling `terminate()` (while `kill()` still messes up the terminal for me).

Answer (score 2):

> What i want to achieve is: launch a subprocess (a command line radio player) that also outputs data to the terminal and can also receive input -- wait for a while -- terminate the subprocess -- exit the shell. I am running python 2.7 on OSX 10.9

On my system, `mplayer` accepts keyboard commands e.g., `q` to stop playing and quit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shlex
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = shlex.split("mplayer http://www.swissradio.ch/streams/6034.m3u")
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE)
time.sleep(5)
p.communicate(b'q')
```

It starts `mplayer` tuned to public domain classical; waits 5 seconds; asks `mplayer` to quit and waits for it to exit. The output is going to terminal (the same place where the python script's output goes).

I've also tried `p.kill()`, `p.terminate()`, `p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` (<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>). `p.kill()` creates *the impression* that the process hangs. Possible explanation: `p.kill()` leaves some pipes open e.g., if `stdout=PIPE` then your Python script might hang at `p.stdout.read()` i.e., it kills the parent `mplayer` process but there might be a child process that holds the pipes open. Nothing hangs with `p.terminate()`, `p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` -- `mplayer` exits in an orderly manner. None of the variants I've tried require `reset`.

---

> how should I go about having both input from Python and keyboard? Do I need two different subprocesses and how to redirect the keyboard input to PIPE?

It would be much simpler just to drop `stdin=PIPE` and call `p.terminate(); p.wait()` instead of `p.communicate(b'q')`.

If you want to keep `stdin=PIPE` then the general principle is: read from `sys.stdin`, write to `p.stdin` until timeout happens. Given that `mplayer` expects one letter commands, you need to be able to [read one character at at time from `sys.stdin`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/4279). The write part is easy: `p.stdin.write(c)` (set `bufsize=0` to avoid buffering on Python side. `mplayer` doesn't buffer its stdin so you don't need to worry about it).

You don't need two different subprocesses. To implement `timeout`, you could use `threading.Timer(5, p.stdin.write, [b'q']).start()` or `select.select` on `sys.stdin` with timeout.

> I guess something using the good old raw_input has nothing to do with it, or?

`raw_input()` is not suitable for `mplayer` because it reads the full lines but `mplayer` expects one character at a time.

Comment: Indeed, this is always better than an explicit kill.  Note however that the "clean" way to complete this is to add a timeout on clean child process exit and forcibly kill the process if the timeout elapses, which brings us back to the initial question :-)

Comment: @AndréCaron: I've added explanation on what happens on `p.kill()`. If we are talking about hypotheticals; there is no "clean" way in general: `kill -9 someprocess_pid` may [fail to kill descendant processes spawned by `someprocess` (new process group, new session, daemon process)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279) or it even may [fail to kill the process itself ("unaccessible nfs")](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/1321).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian +1 This works like a charm. I was wondering what is the `b` in the `p.communicate(b'q')` line? With this method the player does not accept input from the keyboard. Do you know how to fix that? Is it because of `stdin=PIPE`, but then again, without it `p. communicate` will not work, right?

Comment: `b''` is a `bytes` literal in Python (2.7 and 3). It makes the code work on both Python 2.7 and Python 3 without any changes. Yes, if `stdin=PIPE` then `mplayer` accepts input from a pipe, not terminal. If you want to accept input from keyboard, remove `stdin=PIPE` and type `q` yourself. If you want *both* send input from Python and from keyboard then read keyboard input in Python and send it to the subprocess explicitly

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you very much. I know this has nothing to do with the initial question but how should I go about having both input from Python and keyboard? Do I need two different subprocesses and how to redirect the keyboard input to `PIPE`? I guess something using the good old `raw_input` has nothing to do with it, or?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I meant clean for the controlling process, not for the child.