# Compare methods to terminate running a function after time period

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, multiprocessing

I have a program, which opens a lot of urls and downloads pictures .
I have a function of the program, which manages link's opening and pictures downloading, which contains a `for loop` and performs some operations on the priority queue. I want to run this function, but no longer than the set time period. For example if this function is running longer than 1 hour I want to terminate it and run the rest of the program (other functions).
I was trying to find some solutions, and I found two question here on stack.
The first solution use only `time` module [First solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-some-amount-of-time)

The second use also the `multiprocessing` module 
[Second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920384/stop-code-after-time-period). Can some one suggest which one will be more appropriate to use in my program? I will write a pseudocode of my function:

```
def fun():
 for link in linkList:
   if link not in queue:
     queue.push(link)
   else:
     queue.updatePriority(link)
 if queue:
   top = queue.pop()
   fun(top)
```

This function is called in other function:
def run(startLink):
 fun(startLink)

And the run() function is called in other module.
Which method is better to use with a program which contains a lot of modules and performs a lot of

Answer (score 1):

The [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) module is ideal for this task.

You can create a future, then use `asyncio.wait` which supports a timeout parameter.

Comment: @But I want use the built-in modules

Comment: The asyncio module is built-in.

Comment: The OP is using 2.7 - see the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Using `multiprocessing` here would be a little bit tricky, because `fun` is consuming a priority queue (I'm assuming a [`Queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue)) that is coming from some other part of the program. That `queue` cannot easily be passed between processes - you would need to create a custom [`multiprocessing.BaseManager` subclass](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers), register the `Queue.PriorityQueue` class with it, and start up the `Manager` server, instantiate a `PriorityQueue` on the server, and use a `Proxy` to that instance everywhere you interact with the queue. That's a lot of overhead, and also hurts performance a bit.

Since it appears you don't actually want any concurrency here - you want the rest of the program to stop while `fun` is running - I don't think there's a compelling reason to use `multiprocessing`. Instead, I think using the `time`-based solution makes more sense.