# Start python file everyday at 10pm for 12hours

Tags: python, time

How can I set up starting of python file everyday at same time but after 12hours stop

Comment: This question isn't unclear, they're asking how to set a python script to run every day at 10pm for 12 hours. Could one of the close voters clarify their confusion?

Comment: I'm not one of the close voters, but this question could be interpreted as being OS-specific, so at least specifying which OS would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cron to start at same time every day:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto
```

In your code, note the time the program starts using `datetime.now()` and in the main loop of your program, run until it is 12 hours later

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your OS, etc., but here's a general approach:

**Step 1**:  Write a python script that terminates after 12 hours.  (Trivial -- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920384/stop-code-after-time-period))

**Step 2**:  If you're using ubuntu, you can create a crontab and then do the following:

~$ crontab -e

Which will then open up a text file named "crontab" in nano, vim, whatever.

**Step3**:  Next, append this line to the crontab so that the script executes everyday at 10PM:

0 22 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py

If you've programmed the script correctly, then it should terminate after 12 hours.

Check out this helpful Digital Ocean [reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps) for more details on using crontab.