# Auto close open python script

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a tool to auto open and close a python script.
For example, I would like my python script opens every 12 hours. In my script I have an infite loop. So after 12 hours, I need the script to be closed and reopened. Thank you.

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: I am on a google cloud vm, Debian GNU/LINUX

Comment: You could maybe use the [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) python library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the watch command to open your script every 12 hours.
More information on watch and an example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/430382/repeat-a-command-every-x-interval-of-time-in-terminal.

Closing the script can be done from within your script. More information and an example: [Stop code after time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920384/stop-code-after-time-period)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be create main proces with timer and start or close [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)