# Setting the time for the process in Python

Tags: python

I would like set a limit time for process in python, because this process doesn't end with itself.
It is something like this:

```
def forever():
    pass

somethink_to_do_this_20_secounds:
    forever()

print("this print after 20 seconds of forever() work")
```

I found a topic about checking program execution time, but I did not find setting the time limit for the program [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution/1557584#1557584)

How i can realize this somethink_to_do_this_20_secounds in Python? By using subprocess?

Comment: Is you code formatted correctly? Is forever() using a loop?

Comment: check this if it may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920384/stop-code-after-time-period

Comment: You want to set limit on the function or a process ?

Comment: You can also use signal, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Comment: You mentioned "subprocess" , why do you need it in your case?

Comment: @HetalThaker thanks, i check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the concurrent module to  fire a separate thread and wait for it 20 seconds.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
from time import sleep


def forever():
    sleep(21)

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
future = pool.submit(forever)
try:
    result = future.result(20)
except TimeoutError:
    print("Timeout")

print("this print after 20 seconds of forever() work")
```