# Popen returning 0 even on "abnormal program termination"

Tags: python, subprocess

I have used the code given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6001858/282155

For cmd, I am giving .exe of my c++ program.
The solution given there works out for Timeout. But when my c++ program crashes in run-time I want to return non-zero from **RunCmd.Run()**

For this, as mentioned by Eli Bandersky in
[How to get exit code when using Python subprocess communicate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method)
I added the following line:

***return self.p.returncode***

But this returns zero.

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the language.

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: ... in addition, what does it mean "the program crash"? Does that program correctly set its return status to non-zero on case of abnormal termination?

Comment: @Sylvian,
   The code exactly like its there in thread# 4158502 (The first link I mentioned).

a) The difference is at the end i had put return self.p.returncode.
b) The crash happens in c++ code mentioned as [b]cmd[/b] in run time for some cases. 

To give a simple example:
In c++ code:
float df = 4.5/gh; //say gh=0 in some cases