# How to only wait a certain amount of time for a system call to run

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I am making a simple ping script in python, and was looking to add functionality for getting host names for IPs that are up. To do this, im getting the output of `nmblookup -A {ip}` using `os.popen`, and parsing the output. the problem im running into is that for systems where nmblookup wont work (such as routers), the command takes a long time to get an error, whereas when the command runs successfully, it retruns results in under a second. My question is how to only wait N seconds for the `nmblookup` command to return something, and if it doesn't, move on with the program? PS, this is all in linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kill or terminate subprocess when timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158502/kill-or-terminate-subprocess-when-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the command with timeout.
Refer to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) of it.

You can do a Popen and run your command as

```
root@ak-dev:~# timeout 1 sleep 20
root@ak-dev:~# echo $?
124
```