# Best way to fork multiple shell commands/processes in Python?

Tags: python, shell

Most of the examples I've seen with `os.fork` and the subprocess/multiprocessing modules show how to fork a new instance of the calling python script or a chunk of python code.  What would be the best way to spawn a set of arbitrary shell command concurrently?

I suppose, I could just use `subprocess.call` or one of the `Popen` commands and pipe the output to a file, which I believe will return immediately, at least to the caller.  I know this is not that hard to do, I'm just trying to figure out the simplest, most Pythonic way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

All calls to `subprocess.Popen` return immediately to the caller. It's the calls to `wait` and `communicate` which block. So all you need to do is spin up a number of processes using `subprocess.Popen` (set stdin to /dev/null for safety), and then one by one call `communicate` until they're all complete.

Naturally I'm assuming you're just trying to start a bunch of unrelated (i.e. not piped together) commands.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I need.  I am trying to do just that.  I want  to fork the process(es), let them do their thing and come back later on, after running a number of other commands, to grep their output.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose, I could just us subprocess.call or one of the Popen
>   commands and pipe the output to a file, which I believe will return
>   immediately, at least to the caller.

That's not a good way to do it if you want to process the data.

In this case, better do

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and then `sp.communicate()` or read directly from `sp.stdout.read()`.

If the data shall be processed in the calling program at a later time, there are two ways to go:

1. You can retrieve the data ASAP, maybe via a separate thread, reading them and storing them somewhere where the consumer can get them.
2. You can have the producing subprocess have block and retrieve the data from it when you need them. The subprocess produces as many data as fit in the pipe buffer (usually 64 kiB) and then blocks on further writes. As soon as you need the data, you `read()` from the subprocess object's `stdout` (maybe `stderr` as well) and use them - or, again, you use `sp.communicate()` at that later time.

Way 1 would the way to go if producing the data needs much time, so that your wprogram would have to wait.

Way 2 would be to be preferred if the size of the data is quite huge and/or the data is produced so fast that buffering would make no sense.

Comment: I should have added that I do want to process the data but not right away i.e. it may be a long running process, a server of some sort and after I fork it, my script will be off doing other things.  When I come back to the forked process, I might just grep its output file for errors. . .

Answer (score 1):

I like to use PTYs instead of pipes. For a bunch of processes where I only want to capture error messages I did this.

```
RNULL = open('/dev/null', 'r')
WNULL = open('/dev/null', 'w')
logfile = open("myprocess.log", "a", 1)
REALSTDERR = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = logfile
```

This next part was in a loop spawning about 30 processes.

```
sys.stderr = REALSTDERR
master, slave = pty.openpty()
self.subp = Popen(self.parsed, shell=False, stdin=RNULL, stdout=WNULL, stderr=slave)
sys.stderr = logfile
```

After this I had a `select` loop which collected any error messages and sent them to the single log file. Using PTYs meant that I never had to worry about partial lines getting mixed up because the line discipline provides simple framing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no best for all possible circumstances. The best depends on the problem at hand.

Here's how to spawn a process and save its output to a file combining stdout/stderr:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def spawn(cmd, output_file):
    on_posix = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, close_fds=on_posix, bufsize=-1,
                            stdin=open(os.devnull,'rb'),
                            stdout=output_file,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

To spawn multiple processes that can run in parallel with your script and each other:

```
processes, files = [], []
try:
    for i, cmd in enumerate(commands):
        files.append(open('out%d' % i, 'wb'))
        processes.append(spawn(cmd, files[-1]))
finally:
    for p in processes:
        p.wait()
    for f in files: 
        f.close()
```

Note: `cmd` is a list everywhere.

Comment: "There is no best for all possible circumstances." - I think that's true most of the time, I guess I just want some recommendations.

Comment: @mrmbd: I've meant to say that the question is too broad for such a complex topic.

Answer (score 0):

See [an older answer of mine including code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575554/python-subprocess-with-timeout-and-large-output-64k/7753658#7753658) to do:

- Uses processes not threads for blocking I/O because they can more reliably be p.terminated()
- Implements a retriggerable timeout watchdog that restarts counting whenever some output happens
- Implements a long-term timeout watchdog to limit overall runtime
- Can feed in stdin (although I only need to feed in one-time short strings)
- Can capture stdout/stderr in the usual Popen means (Only stdout is coded, and stderr redirected to stdout; but can easily be separated)
- It's almost realtime because it only checks every 0.2 seconds for output. But you could decrease this or remove the waiting interval easily
- Lots of debugging printouts still enabled to see whats happening when.

For spawning multiple concurrent commands, you would need to alter the class RunCmd to instantiate mutliple read output/write input queues and to spawn mutliple Popen subprocesses.