# How do I create a subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to create a subprocess of a process.

What would be a working example which shows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Start with the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) documentation.

If you want to get the output:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.Popen(['uname', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> output
'Linux'
```

If you just want to call and not deal with the output:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['echo', 'Hi'])
Hi
0
```

[subprocess.check_call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) is the same except that it throws up a `CalledProcessError` in case the command is called with invalid parameters.

A [good subprocess tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/).

Comment: yes that what i want. one more question, when i will use "output = subprocess.Popen(['uname', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0] " this command, this runs perfectly fine... but if i have to run like "rdiff-backup -v --force <> <> <> <>" then if i split them using spaces and apply that list to this command gives me error...so my question is do i have to write my command in list by splitting with spaces???

Comment: You should have a list preferably as arguments to `Popen`. If you have a string, do a string.split() and then pass it to `Popen`.

Comment: thanks sukhbir, I have done that splitting of list but not working with this...also this output is the output which comes when complete execution occurs...how to retrieve the continuous output, rather than taking output after complete executaion?

Comment: The whole purpose of the `communicate` method is to wait for the process to finish and return all the output. If you don't want to wait, don't call `communicate`. Instead, read from the stdout or stderr attribute to read the output.

Comment: sorry i am new in this python so asking loads of questions, but we are reading from stdout itself in our command - " subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.Popen(['uname', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
"...then can you please elaborate?

Comment: We are reading from the terminal and not the standard input/ output. Notice: `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: oh ok. then can you please tell me how to read using subprocesses for cont. output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874815/how-do-i-get-real-time-information-back-from-a-subprocess-popen-in-python-2-5

Comment: thanks sukhbir, that means i can write as --->>>  subprocess
>>> output = subprocess.Popen(['uname', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
 and then, while output.poll() is None:
    out = output.stdout.readline()...i will try this...

Comment: You should try it and let me know also cause I have never tried it :)

Answer (score 3):

**Launching and monitoring a subprocess:**

```
import subprocess, time, os, signal
args=['/usr/bin/vmstat','-n','2']
app=subprocess.Popen(args=args, stdout=open('somefile','w'))
print "Your app's PID is %s. You can now process data..." % app.pid
time.sleep(5)
if app.poll() == None: print "Process is still running after 5s."
print "The app outputed %s bytes." % len(open('somefile','r').read())
print "Stopping the process..."
os.kill(app.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

There is more to it.  Just check the [Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['echo', 'hello world'])
```

Comment: what subprocess.call does? i am running a file named test.py and i want to run it creating subprocess. did it means that i have to run it like subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py']) ?

Comment: take a look at the docs, http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: thanks dan. only thing which i did not understand is if i am running a file named test.py and i want to run it creating subprocess. did it means that i have to run it like subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py'])?

Comment: why do you need to create a new interpreter and not just use execfile? subprocess.call is a blocking function, if you need non-blocking operation then use subprocess.Popen instead.

Comment: means did subprocess.Popen will create a new process?

Comment: both Popen and call will create a new process, but call waits until the process has finished before it returns.

Comment: @sasa: If your new 'process' is in Python, you could look into `execfile`, or threading, or multiprocessing, depending on what you want to do. `subprocess` is used to tell your computer to run an entirely separate program.

Comment: yes that what i want. one more question, when i will use "output = subprocess.Popen(['uname', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0] " this command, this runs perfectly fine... but if i have to run like "rdiff-backup -v --force <> <> <> <>" then if i split them using spaces and apply that list to this command gives me error...so my question is do i have to write my command in list by splitting with spaces???

Comment: you can using shlex.split to form a list from a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me if you want to run a simple command instead of giving a seperate file

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print process.returncode
```

To get returncode of process you can use `process.returncode`
To get response you can use `process.communicate()`

in case if you are confuse you can just test this code by using `command="ls"`

if you are getting `returncode` other than `0` then you can check here what that error code means: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

For more details about Subprocess: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if os.name == 'nt':
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.call(os.popen(tempFileName), shell=True)
os.remove(tempFileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on user225312's answer, I prepared the below one liner, it may help you to test the subprocess:

```
python -c "import subprocess;
output = subprocess.Popen(['uname', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]; 
print output"
```

result like:
`Linux xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 29 14:49:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`