# Communication between python and C

Tags: python, c

I have a command line program developed in c. Lets say, i have a parser written in C. Now i am developing a project with gui in python and i need that parser for python project. In c we can invoke a system call and redirect the output to system.out or a file. Is there are any way to do this python? I have both code and executable file of c program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python - how to create a subprocess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488255/python-how-to-create-a-subprocess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, go for a subprocess. Docs are here: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Answer (score 1):

To call other programs and interact with them use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.