# How to communicate with command line program using python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

```
import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(["program.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE) #the cmd program opens
proc.communicate(input="filename.txt") #here the filename should be entered (runs)
#then the program asks to enter a number:
proc.communicate(input="1") #(the cmd stops here and nothing is passed)
proc.communicate(input="2") # (same not passing anything)
```

How do I pass and communicate with the cmd using python.

(using windows platform)

Comment: Why don't you also paste the relevant parts of the receiver process here?

Comment: can try something like `proc.stdin.write(data_to_write)`

Answer (score 6):

The [docs on `communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) explain this:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

`communicate()` blocks once the input has been sent until the program finishes executing. In your example, the program waits for more input after you send `"1"`, but Python waits for it to exit before it gets to the next line, meaning the whole thing deadlocks.

If you want to read and write a lot interchangeably, [make pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874815/how-do-i-get-real-time-information-back-from-a-subprocess-popen-in-python-2-5) to `stdin`/`stdout` and write/read to/from them.

Comment: Thanks it helps me understand now what to do next.

Comment: @ user1717522 -- if you find a satisfying answer to your question, you should mark it as accepted.