# how to get continous output from command line?

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

Following code will get command line output of executing another program:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate()[0]
```

But some programs like wget, ffmpeg will display a progress bar in command line, and update its value all the time, like this:

> 12% [---                                   ] 105,691     50.6K/s  eta
>   1h 43m

I tried above code to get output of wget but it failed. it cannot get the output until wget finished executing, and the output is an empty string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess