# How to Get Specific Data from a CLI program output in Python ?

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-interface, output

I have a CLI program (a downloader) which is returning the following line when operating :

[*****..........] xx.x% yyy,yyMb out of zzz,zzMb

I am launching this with a subprocess in Python, and I'd like to know how I can capture the output and how I can selectively get:
- the percentage info
- the downloaded amount in Mb info
- the total size of the file in Mb

Appreciate your help (Python 2.6 compatible solution, please).

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess

Comment: Thanks, it provides only one part of the answer though. How do I get the % and size out of the stdout ?

Comment: You could use the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents), or if you really know the format & don't want to indulge in regular expressions, simple `str.split("%")` might do the trick.