# How can I git clone a repository with python, and get the progress of the clone process?

Tags: python, git

I'd like to be able to git clone a large repository using python, using some library, but importantly I'd like to be able to see the progress of the clone as it's happening. I tried pygit2 and GitPython, but they don't seem to show their progress. Is there another way?

Comment: How do you want to show the progress? In a GUI or on stdout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155452/read-git-clones-output-in-real-time

Comment: @Robᵩ, I was thinking just the normal way the CLI git command shows you the progress, e.g. grabbing object 11/27...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`RemoteProgress`](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.remote.RemoteProgress) from [GitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Here is a crude example:

```
import git

class Progress(git.remote.RemoteProgress):
    def update(self, op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message=''):
        print 'update(%s, %s, %s, %s)'%(op_code, cur_count, max_count, message)

repo = git.Repo.clone_from(
    'https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython',
    './git-python',
    progress=Progress())
```

Or use this `update()` function for a slightly more refined message format:

```
    def update(self, op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message=''):
        print self._cur_line
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to get the clone information, no need to install `gitpython`, you can get it directly from standard error stream through built-in `subprocess` module.

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

os.chdir(r"C:\Users")  # The repo storage directory you want

url = "https://github.com/USER/REPO.git"  # Target clone repo address

proc = Popen(
    ["git", "clone", "--progress", url],
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True, text=True
)

for line in proc.stdout:
    if line:
        print(line.strip())  # Now you get all terminal clone output text
```

You can see some clone command relative informations after execute the command `git help clone`.

> `--progress`
>
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default
> when it is attached to a terminal, unless `--quiet` is specified. This
> flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not
> directed to a terminal.