# Python3 subprocess.Popen handle carriage return

Tags: python, stdout, popen, carriage-return

I'm trying to wrap a `git clone` command with `subprocess.Popen` (python3) and consume stdout in real-time. Something like

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
  ["git.exe", "clone", "https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project"],
  stdin=None,
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b""):
  print(line)
```

which only produces the intial

```
b"Cloning into 'llvm-project'...\n"
```

and then "hangs" for quite a while. The problem seems to be that the clone command contains a lot of `\r` lines which get buffered until the very end and flushed at once - I know the progress can be disabled but I *do* want them. I'd like to treat `\r` like `\n` somehow and continuously receive them. I tried `read(1)` as well but it does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get subprocess stdout while running git command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986533/how-to-get-subprocess-stdout-while-running-git-command)

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155452/read-git-clones-output-in-real-time