# Popen redirect sdtout during long process

Tags: python-3.x, popen

I have made some tests to redirect stdout during long process.

I have got some result that I don't understand.

*run.py*

```
import contextlib
import subprocess
import sys

newlines = ['\n', '\r\n', '\r']


def example1():
    #stupid test, for fun
    cmd = ['python', 'in.py']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=sys.stdout,
        stderr=sys.stderr,
    )

def example2():

    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess
    def unbuffered(proc, stream='stdout'):
        stream = getattr(proc, stream)
        while True:
            out = []
            last = stream.read(1)
            # Don't loop forever
            if last == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
                break
            while last not in newlines:
                # Don't loop forever
                if last == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
                    break
                out.append(last)
                last = stream.read(1)
            out = ''.join(out)
            print(out)

    cmd = ['python', 'in.py']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        # Make all end-of-lines '\n'
        universal_newlines=True,
    )
    for line in unbuffered(proc):
        print(line)

def example3():
    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running
    cmd = ['python', 'in.py']
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    lines_iterator = iter(popen.stdout.readline, b"")
    while popen.poll() is None:
        for line in lines_iterator:
            nline = line.rstrip()
            print(nline.decode("latin"), end="\r\n",flush=True)
```

*in.py*

```
import random
import sys
import time

END = 10

for i in range(END):
    print(i)
    if i == random.randint(1, END-2):
        sys.stderr.write('Error, out !!!\n')
        sys.exit(i)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

*example1*:

Surprise... I can redirect the stdout to the console (doesn't work with bpython). Weirdly I must press a key to finish the process.

*example2* and *example3*:

Output print only at the sub-process end.

I'm fairly new in subprocessing, thanks for any explanation. :)

Comment: do not just dump all the code that you have. Create a [*minimal* (but complete) code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates *a single problem* that you are trying to solve. If there are multiple issues, start with one (but provide a wider context). [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28240794/edit) and specify explicitly: what do you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: try: `python -u in.py`. Related: [Python C program subprocess hangs at “for line in iter”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)

Comment: Nice !!! Extactly what I need. Thanks a lot.