# Print tqdm progress bar from external python script called by subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, google-colaboratory, popen, tqdm

My *main goal* is to run an external python script (client script) by `subprocess` in another python script (caller script). The console of the caller script displays all output from the client script *except* the tqdm output - so it is not a general problem of displaying output by `subprocess`, but a specific problem related to `subprocess` interacting with `tqdm`.

My *secondary goal* is that I'd like to understand it :). So thoughtful explanations are much appreciated.

The client script (train.py) contains several tqdm calls. So far, I haven't seen much difference in outputs between various tqdm argument configurations, so let's use the simplest one.

In `train.py`:

```
...
from tqdm import tqdm

with tqdm(total = 10, ncols = 80,
          file=sys.stdout, position = 0, leave = True,
          desc='f5b: pbar.set_postfix') as pbar:
    for i in range(10):
        pbar.update(1)
        postfix = {'loss': '{0:.4f}'.format(1+i)}
        pbar.set_postfix(**postfix)
        sleep(0.1)
```

The caller script `experiment.py` executes the function `execute_experiment` which calls `train.py` by the argument `command_list`:

```
def execute_experiment(command_list):
    tic = time.time()
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            command_list, shell=False, 
            encoding='utf-8',
            bufsize=0,
            stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            universal_newlines=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
            )
        # Poll process for new output until finished
        # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37401654/7769076
        while process.poll() is None:
            nextline = process.stdout.readline()
            sys.stdout.write(nextline)
            sys.stdout.flush()

    except CalledProcessError as err:
        print("CalledProcessError: {0}".format(err))
        sys.exit(1)

    except OSError as err:
        print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
        sys.exit(1)

    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

    if (process.returncode == 0):
        toc = time.time()
        time1 = str(round(toc - tic))
        return time1
    else:
        return 1
```

This script call to the above code snipped of train.py does return output but the tqdm output is stopped after 0 seconds and looks like this:

```
f5b: pbar.set_postfix:   0%|                             | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
f5b: pbar.set_postfix:  10%|█▊                | 1/10 [00:00<00:00, 22310.13it/s]
```

The script call to the original code of train.py returns all output *except* tqdm output:

```
Training default configuration
train.py data --use-cuda ...
device: cuda
...
```

### Comments:

1. `shell = False`: As python script calls python script. When `shell=True`, the client script is not called at all
2. `bufsize=0`: To prevent buffering
3. The `train.py` call is preceded with `sys.executable` to ensure that the python interpreter of the corresponding conda environment is called when on local machine.

### Questions:

1. Does `tqdm.set_postfix` prevent passing the progress bar output upstream? I know this happens when `tqdm.set_description` is invoked, e.g. by:

   pbar.set_description('processed: %d' %(1 + i))

This code contains it:

```
def train(self, dataloader, max_batches=500, verbose=True, **kwargs):
    with tqdm(total=max_batches, disable=not verbose, **kwargs) as pbar:
        for results in self.train_iter(dataloader, max_batches=max_batches):
            pbar.update(1)
            postfix = {'loss': '{0:.4f}'.format(results['mean_outer_loss'])}

            if 'accuracies_after' in results:
                postfix['accuracy'] = '{0:.4f}'.format(
                    np.mean(results['accuracies_after']))
            pbar.set_postfix(**postfix)
    # for logging
    return results
```

2. Is the nested function call the reason why the progress bar is not shown?

The order of calls is `experiment.py` > `train.py`  > `nested.py`.

`train.py` calls the train function in `nested.py` by:

for epoch in range(args.num_epochs):

```
results_metatraining = metalearner.train(meta_train_dataloader,
                  max_batches=args.num_batches,
                  verbose=args.verbose,
                  desc='Training',
                  # leave=False
                  leave=True
                  )
```

---

Alternatives tried out with no success:

```
    ### try2
    process = subprocess.Popen(command_list, shell=False, encoding='utf-8',
                               stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline().strip()
        print('output: ' + output)
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:  # end of output
            break
        if output: # print output in realtime
            print(output)
    else:
        output = process.communicate()
    process.wait()


    ### try6
    process = subprocess.Popen(command_list, shell=False,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line 
    process.stdout.close()
    return_code = process.wait()
    print('return_code' + str(return_code))
    if return_code:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, command_list)


    ### try7
    with subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                          bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        while True:
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print(line)    
        exit_code = p.poll()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think readline is waiting for '\n', and tqdm is not creating new lines, maybe this could help (I did not try):

```
import io
def execute_experiment(command_list):
    tic = time.time()
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            command_list, shell=False, 
            encoding='utf-8',
            bufsize=1,
            stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            universal_newlines=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
            )
        # Poll process for new output until finished
        # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37401654/7769076
        reader = io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, encoding='utf8')
        while process.poll() is None:
            char = reader.read(1)
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()

    except CalledProcessError as err:
        print("CalledProcessError: {0}".format(err))
        sys.exit(1)

    except OSError as err:
        print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
        sys.exit(1)

    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

    if (process.returncode == 0):
        toc = time.time()
        time1 = str(round(toc - tic))
        return time1
    else:
        return 1
```