# Reading stdout from a subprocess in real time

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

Given this code snippet:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError


def execute(cmd):
    with Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line, end='')

    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)

base_cmd = [
    "cmd", "/c", "d:\\virtual_envs\\py362_32\\Scripts\\activate",
    "&&"
]
cmd1 = " ".join(base_cmd + ['python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"'])
cmd2 = " ".join(base_cmd + ["python -m http.server"])
```

If I run `execute(cmd1)` the output will be printed without any problems.

However, If I run `execute(cmd2)` instead nothing will be printed, why is that and how can I fix it so I could see the http.server's output in real time.

Also, how `for line in p.stdout` is been evaluated internally? is it some sort of endless loop till reaches stdout eof or something?

This topic has already been addressed few times here in SO but I haven't found a windows solution. The above snippet is code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319191/3809375) and I'm running http.server from a virtualenv (python3.6.2-32bits on win7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to read continuously from a running subprocess, you have to make *that* process' output unbuffered. Your subprocess being a Python program, this can be done by passing `-u` to the interpreter:

`python -u -m http.server`

This is how it looks on a Windows box.

[image]

Comment: Works for me, although I felt no desire to fire up a Windows box for that and thus removed your `cmd /c ...` stuff.

Comment: Streams and buffering work more or less the same on Windows and other OS. See the screenshot in my updated answer. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @fpbhb you can remove the `" ".join` as it does nothing when executed on single element in a list.

Answer (score 7):

With this code, you can`t see the real-time output because of buffering:

```
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line, end='')
```

But if you use `p.stdout.readline()` it should work:

```
while True:
  line = p.stdout.readline()
  if not line: break
  print(line, end='')
```

See corresponding [python bug discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue3907) for details

**UPD:** here you can find almost the same [problem with various solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main problem is that `http.server` somehow is logging the output to `stderr`, here I have an example with `asyncio`, reading the data either from `stdout` or `stderr`.

My first attempt was to use asyncio, a nice API, which exists in since Python 3.4. Later I found a simpler solution, so you can choose, both of em should work.

## asyncio as solution

In the background asyncio is using [IOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_completion_port) -  a windows API to async stuff.

```
# inspired by https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/subprocesses.html

import asyncio
import sys
import time

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

async def run_webserver():
    buffer = bytearray()

    # start the webserver without buffering (-u) and stderr and stdin as the arguments
    print('launching process')
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        sys.executable, '-u', '-mhttp.server',
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    print('process started {}'.format(proc.pid))
    while 1:
        # wait either for stderr or stdout and loop over the results
        for line in asyncio.as_completed([proc.stderr.readline(), proc.stdout.readline()]):
            print('read {!r}'.format(await line))

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    event_loop.run_until_complete(run_df())
finally:
    event_loop.close()
```

## redirecting the from stdout

based on your example this is a really simple solution. It just redirects the stderr to stdout and only stdout is read.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError, run, STDOUT import os

def execute(cmd):
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1) as p:
        while 1:
            print('waiting for a line')
            print(p.stdout.readline())

cmd2 = ["python", "-u", "-m", "http.server"]

execute(cmd2)
```

Answer (score 3):

> How for line in p.stdout is been evaluated internally? is it some sort of endless loop till reaches stdout eof or something?

`p.stdout` is a buffer (blocking). When you are reading from an *empty* buffer, you are blocked until something is written to that buffer. Once something is in it, you get the data and execute the inner part.

Think of how `tail -f` works on linux: it waits until something is written to the file, and when it does it echo's the new data to the screen. What happens when there is no data? **it waits.** So when your program gets to this line, it waits for data and process it.

As your code works, but when run as a model not, it has to be related to this somehow. The `http.server` module probably buffers the output. Try adding `-u` parameter to Python to run the process as unbuffered:

> -u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
>            see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'

Also, you might want to try change your loop to `for line in iter(lambda: p.stdout.read(1), ''):`, as this reads `1` byte at a time before processing.

---

*Update*: The full loop code is

```
for line in iter(lambda: p.stdout.read(1), ''):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Also, you pass your command as a string. Try passing it as a list, with each element in its own slot:

```
cmd = ['python', '-m', 'http.server', ..]
```

Comment: @BPL I've updated my answer to include the loop content, and another suggestion you can try

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the no-buffer behavior at the OS level.

In Linux, you could wrap your existing command line with `stdbuf` :

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 YOURCOMMAND
```

Or in Windows, you could wrap your existing command line with `winpty`:

```
winpty.exe -Xallow-non-tty -Xplain YOURCOMMAND
```

I'm not aware of OS-neutral tools for this.