# unable to get real time stdout and stderr with python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Am able to read the python subprocess stdout using below method in real time,

```
import subprocess
command = "/tmp/testscript"
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    print(output)
    if output.decode() == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
        break
```

But when I try to read both `stdout` and `stderr` in real time its not working as expected and getting the data printed on the console only when the subprocess execution completes.

```
import subprocess
command = "/tmp/test.sh"
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    error = proc.stderr.readline()
    print(output)
    print(error)
    if output.decode() == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
        break
```

As far as what I understood is that in the while it just read the lines of stdout and then stderr, then printing both the variable values and moving to next loop, but not sure why its not working as expected. Any idea would be helpful.

Note : Am using python3.7

Comment: Classical deadlock famine problem with 2 blocked reads on 2 streams. Why not merging both output & error streams with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` ? that would avoid a complex thread mechanism.

Comment: something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre For just testing purpose am printing on the console. but actual case will be write stdout and stderr data on separate file for monitoring purpose.

Comment: in that case, use 2 separate threads.