# Display subprocess output in real time

Tags: python, subprocess

Curently I am using subporcess library on widows to execute comand in cmd. My problem is that I would like to display the output of cmd in the real time. I am able to display output after comand exececute her job. Is it possible to do display the output in real time?

My code looks like this:

```
import subprocess

def get_output(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    return output.decode('utf-8')

print(get_output('ping 8.8.8.8'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting realtime output using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command

Comment: It does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be helpful to You?

```
  import subprocess
  import shlex

    def get_output(command):
        process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while True:
            output = process.stdout.readline()
            if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
                break
            if output:
                print output.strip()
        rc = process.poll()
        return rc
```

You might find helpful [this link](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python).