# Powershell - Display subprocess output in real-time

Tags: powershell

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143711/display-subprocess-output-in-real-time) - I would like to know how to display the output of an external command in real-time. I am able to display the output of a command after it's fully executed. But is it possible to display the output in real-time (*as the command is executing*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "ping.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "-n 20 google.com"
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
while (-not $p.HasExited) {
    if (-not $p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
        # Just for fun
        $lineChars = $p.StandardOutput.ReadLine().ToCharArray() 
        [Array]::Reverse($lineChars)
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan ([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($lineChars))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! This is exactly what I needed.. besides the reverse text ;)