# Can TQDM track the output of a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, tqdm

As part of a long pipeline (all orchestrated in Python), I'm calling an external program using the subprocess module. This program takes a while to finish, so I'd like to show the user a nice progress bar, to reassure them that it hasn't frozen.

This program also sends a whole lot of information to stdout—much more than I want to show the end user. But the number of lines in this output is consistent.

What's the best way to track the number of lines that have been sent to stdout by a subprocess, for the purpose of updating a real-time status bar (via tqdm)?

Comment: @wim I know the total number of expected lines, so I can calculate a percentage based on that. And I like TQDM because it's what I'm used to, but if another option works better for this purpose, I'm happy to switch.

Comment: _grumbles about a ["best way"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing) question vs a [mre] for a narrow, specific problem_ (we _do_ have [questions already existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803265/getting-realtime-output-using-subprocess) with answers that show how to read from a subprocess's stdout line-by-line while it's running; if you encountered a specific problem using one of them, that would make the focus a lot clearer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That linked question actually answers my question perfectly. Feel free to close this one as a duplicate!